# Recursive function definition

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I have been playing around with recursive definition of functions. I posed myself this question. Suppose functions $g,h$ are given $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ functions, and

$$f(x) = g(x) + h(f(x))$$

Can I construct the function $f(x)$ from this definition? What are the requirements on $g,h$ so that $f$ exists?

My idea was that I can write perhaps

$$f(x) = g(x) + h(g(x) + h(g(x) + h(\dots)))$$

and depending on $g,h$ this might converge somehow so that $f(x)$ on the rhs becomes negligible. But I don't know how I can perform the convergence.

Comment: If $h$ is constant it is easy :)

Comment: What exactly is your question -- finding conditions on $h,g$ for which there is a well-defined unique solution? (This won't always be true, of course. If $h=Id$, you have some issue for instance.)

Comment: I wish to know if I can construct the function $f$ from this definition in some "mechanical" way. I also wish to know if there are specific properties of $g,h$ that allow $f$ to exist. I augmented the question.

Comment: $$f=g + h \circ f$$ is a functional equation ($f$ is the unknown), and there is no reason to believe that it has a solution.

Comment: If you want $f$ to be not abiguously defined, it is sufficient to have $Id-h$ injective (so that you can invert it). But that doesn't mean at all you will get out of $f$ anything more than its definition